# Insert react js form data into mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have to insert name field data in to mysql database using express js, fetch  api. Could any one help flow and project structure with simple way. Advance thanks.

```js
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? A basic solution would be to use JQuery or fetch or axios to post data to the backend (express), and then insert it using either an ORM or some other database abstraction library.

Comment: Yes I did. In my App.js file I have written form fetch those form details. Separately I have created server.js file I have got fetched data and connected to databse. When I am running the code showing showing warnings like express/lib/view/.js.  If possible can you tell me what I have to write in the App.js, how to get form data in to server.js using fetch and insert in to mysql. Only one field data like aboove code. @TylerSebastian

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good example of how to connect to a MySQL database using Node on the Express guide. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'dbuser',
  password : 's3kreee7',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect()

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution)
})

connection.end()
```

Hope that helps you get running.

Comment: I want to get the data from front end react js form and insert in to mysql database using backend express. Can you tell me the flow from front end to backend with simple one field form using react js and then insert into database. Thanks. @spencer.sm